# Excel file opened with Interop hangs and won't close

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, vba

I have a web page in ASP.NET C# that opens an Excel file with Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel classes.

The excel file has VBA code that runs on the Workbook_BeforeClose event. 
When opening and closing the file with Excel, the code runs fine, with a prompt to save the changes after the code is run.

But when doing the same on the webpage with C#, the page just loads indefenitly. Debugging shows that it stops(waits?) at the line myExcelWorkbook.Close(true);

Here is what the C# code looks like:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
public string getExcelInfo(string value1, string value2, string mapPath)
{
    Excel.Application myExcelApp;
    Excel.Workbooks myExcelWorkbooks;
    Excel.Workbook myExcelWorkbook;
    object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;    
    myExcelApp = new Excel.Application();
    myExcelWorkbooks = myExcelApp.Workbooks;
    //Copy file to allow simultaneous executions
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int rand = rnd.Next(1000000);
    File.Copy(mapPath+"/App_Data/ConfigAQNX01.xlsm", mapPath+"/App_Data/ConfigAQNX01"+rand.ToString() + ".xlsm");

    //Open file, workbook and sheet
    String fileName = mapPath+"/App_Data/ConfigAQNX01" + rand.ToString() + ".xlsm";
    myExcelWorkbook = myExcelWorkbooks.Open(fileName, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
    Excel.Worksheet myExcelWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)myExcelWorkbook.ActiveSheet;

    //insert values
    myExcelWorksheet.Cells[3, 2] = value1;
    myExcelWorksheet.Cells[6, 2] = value2;

    //Save so formulaes are executed
    myExcelWorkbook.Save();
    myExcelWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)myExcelWorkbook.ActiveSheet;

    //read value in excel

    Excel.Range currentRange = (Excel.Range)myExcelWorksheet.Cells[7, 4];
    string Cost_Cad_Unit = currentRange.Value2.ToString();

    //Close Excel
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(currentRange);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(myExcelWorksheet);

    //Set SaveChange to true on close
    myExcelWorkbook.Close(true);  //This line is where processing takes forever, literraly
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(myExcelWorkbook);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(myExcelWorkbooks);

    myExcelApp.Quit();                                   
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(myExcelApp);

    currentRange = null;
    myExcelWorksheet = null;
    myExcelWorkbook = null;
    myExcelWorkbooks = null;
    myExcelApp = null;

    return Cost_Cad_Unit; 
}
```

Are there options that can be set to get the VBA code to run, or ways to know what makes it hang?  Or are there limitations with Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel to get Workbook_BeforeClose code to run?

Thank you,

Comment: Try this.. change `myExcelWorkbook.Close(true);` to `myExcelWorkbook.Close(false);` and just before that line add this line `myExcelWorkbook.Save();`

Comment: Could you post your close event code?

Comment: I tried changing 
    `myExcelWorkbook.Close(true)`;
to 
    `myExcelWorkbook.Close(false); 
    myExcelWorkbook.Save();`
but it didn't change anything.
In the Excel file, I moved the code to a separate method called GenerateFiles and I am calling it by C# like this: 
    `myExcelApp.Run("GenerateFiles")`
with the same result. 
The Excel file belongs to a customer, so I can't post their code for now.

Comment: Never mind, the GenerateFiles method was crashing because of invalid values in some cells, fixing that made the call work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the VBA code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim FileName, CalcSheet As String
    Dim English As Boolean

    Worksheets("Drawing").Activate
    Worksheets("Drawing OE").Activate
    Worksheets("Interface").Activate

    Worksheets("Parameters").Range("Closing").Formula = "O"
    If Worksheets("Parameters").Range("CreateDrawing").Value = "N" Then Exit Sub

    If Worksheets("Interface").Range("digit_oper").Value = 4 Then
        Sheets(Array("Drawing", "Drawing OE")).Select
    Else
        Sheets(Array("Drawing")).Select
    End If

    Worksheets("Drawing").Activate
    FileName = ActiveSheet.Range("Drawingpdf").Value

    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=FileName, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=False, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

    Worksheets("Calc").Activate
    FileName = ActiveSheet.Range("Calcpdf").Value

    English = Worksheets("Drawing").Range("English").Value
    If English Then CalcSheet = "Calc EN" Else CalcSheet = "Calc"

    Sheets(Array(CalcSheet)).Select
    Worksheets(CalcSheet).Activate

    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=FileName, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=False, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

    Worksheets("Parameters").Range("Closing").Formula = "N"
    Worksheets("Interface").Activate

End Sub
```

I created a new method, GenerateFiles(), moved the code from Workbook_BeforeClose to this method and changing the C# code to : 
    ... 
    myExcelWorkbook.Save();
    myExcelApp.Run("GenerateFiles");
    myExcelWorkbook.Close(false); 
    ...
Now works. 
It's as if myExcelWorkbook.Close creates an infinite loop with Workbook_BeforeClose when the Workbook_BeforeClose method doesn't execute "fast enough"...